# How to set different time slots for a single https requests in jmeter

Tags: datetime, parameters, jmeter, performance-testing, epoch

I have a http request where I need to send random time values in given time frame

Request looks like this:
http://domain/api1?&mt=getEmp&punchTime=1590678744

I've shifts pre-defined
**Morning**: *0900 to 1400*
**Evening**: *1400 to 1900*
**Night**: *1900 to 2300*
Expectation is: random epoch time value between pre-defined shift time slot should be put as punch-time for each request.

I don't want to separate out the request as per different time shifts.

Could anyone please help me to achieve this with JMeter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can calculate the random time stamp in the given range using a suitable [JSR223 Test Element](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/best-practices.html#jsr223) and [Groovy language](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/).

Example code which produces random time between 9 and 14 hour of the current day and store it into `randomMorningTime` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) would be something like:

```
def calendar = Calendar.getInstance()
def morningStart = new GregorianCalendar(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 9, 00).getTimeInMillis()
def morningEnd = new GregorianCalendar(calendar.get(Calendar.YEAR), calendar.get(Calendar.MONTH), calendar.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH), 14, 00).getTimeInMillis()


def randomMorningTime = org.apache.commons.lang3.RandomUtils.nextLong(morningStart, morningEnd)
def timestamp = ( randomMorningTime / 1000).round() as String
log.info('Random morning time for current day: ' + new Date(randomMorningTime))
log.info('Associated timestamp: ' + timestamp)
vars.put('randomMorningTime', timestamp)
```

Demo:

[image]

You will be able to access the generated value as `${randomMorningTime}` where required.

See JavaDoc on [GregorianCalendar](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/GregorianCalendar.html) class for more information

Comment: @https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t Thanks. I have used it as is. But got this error `ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script JSR223 Sampler, message: javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
javax.script.ScriptException: java.lang.NullPointerException
at org.codehaus.groovy.jsr223. GroovyScriptEngineImpl.eval(GroovyScriptEngineImpl.java:324) ~[groovy-all-2.4.16.jar:2.4.16]` ` java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source) [?:1.8.0_241] Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.math.BigDecimal.plus(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_241]`

Comment: `groovy-all-2.4.16.jar` indicates that you're sitting on some of the previous JMeter versions, according to [9 Easy Solutions for a JMeter Load Test “Out of Memory” Failure](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/9-easy-solutions-jmeter-load-test-%E2%80%9Cout-memory%E2%80%9D-failure) you should be using the latest version of JMeter so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.3](http://www.jmeter-archive.org/ANNOUNCE-Apache-JMeter-5-3-released-td5728863.html) and you should be able to use the code provided, otherwise you will have to figure out the changes required yourself.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/users/2897748/dmitri-t This was working like charm. But now when I try to change these timestamps to specific TimeZones like CDT, EDT etc by `def calendar = Calendar.getInstance(TimeZone.getTimeZone("EDT"))` but this is not giving an expected output. I read that GregorianCalendar has some drawback while setting date and times. **But still can we modify this code and get timestamp in specific TimeZone?** TIA